# UISplitViewControllerDelegate never called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I've been trying for days to get `UISplitViewController` to call the delegate. I tried setting it in the `MasterViewController`, I tried setting it in the `DetailViewController`, I tried having the `SVC` as an embedded view controller in a container inside another view controller, and use the `prepareForSegue` call to set the delegate. I tried instantiating it from the Storyboard in the `AppDelegate` and setting the delegate there. The delegate is never ever called. I'm going crazy. 
I'm on the latest non-beta Swift (3.1), on iOS 10.3.1.

I've used the Debugger to check the delegate is in fact set, and remains in memory, however, the methods are never called.

I appreciate any help you can provide me with.

This is my current AppDelegate but I've tried **countless** ways as I said:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true
    if let svc = self.window?.rootViewController as? UISplitViewController {
        svc.delegate = svc.viewControllers.last as! UISplitViewControllerDelegate
    }
    return true
}
```

### Edit 1:

Some of you didn't understand what delegate I'm trying to implement. To clarify, I'm trying to control the delegate of `UISplitViewController`, in other words, the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`. The reason I'm trying to do this is to be able to control the collapsing of views. In the default configuration of the `UISplitViewController`, on an iPhone on portrait mode, it defaults to the `detailViewController`. This behavior is clearly wrong for most apps (and mine). I intend to first show the `masterViewController` that lists the content I have for display, and trigger the `detailViewController` only when an item has been selected.

I would also accept an answer that gave me some alternative way to have that behavior (prefer `masterViewController` on portrait unless my `detailViewController` has content set.

I know you can get the described behavior by not setting a `detailViewController` in the Storyboard, and using the `showDetail` segue when selecting an item, but my problem with that is I can't have a default view when no item has been selected, causing a grey square being shown (not very pretty) when in landscape on an iPad or iPhone Plus.

Comment: Did you find a solution eventually?

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code it's work for me.

In AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    let navViewController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController
    let masterVC = navViewController?.topViewController as? MasterViewController
    let detailViewController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as? DetailsViewController
    masterVC?.delegate = detailViewController

    return true
}
```

In MasterViewController

```
protocol MasterViewControllerDelegate : class{
    func passingData(strName : String)
}

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

       weak var delegate : MasterViewControllerDelegate?

       override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          //Calling Delegate

          delegate?.passingData(strName: "Any Message")

          if let detailViewController = self.delegate as? DetailsViewController {

  splitViewController?.showDetailViewController(detailViewController, sender: nil)
          }
       }
}
```

In DetailViewController

```
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController, MasterViewControllerDelegate{

    //Other IBOutlet and Methods

    //Delegate method of MasterViewControllerDelegate
    func passingData(strName : String)
         print(strName) //OUTPUT: "Any Message"
    }
}
```

I hope it also work for you.

Comment: Your answer is of no use to me unfortunately. As you can see, I’m trying to implement the UISplitviewControllerDelegate, I’m not having problems passing data to the detail view controller, as your answer implies.

Comment: sorry bro! i was used custom protocol not  UISplitviewControllerDelegate